Nuxt 3 create alias for useAppConfig import
I'm working on a Nuxt 3 application where I've copied a module from another project. This module utilizes a custom composable named useAppConfig which is originally imported as @app1/composables/useAppConfig.js.
I aim to integrate this module into my Nuxt 3 project (App2) and establish an alias for the useAppConfig import to streamline its usage.
I've attempted to create an alias within the Nuxt configuration like this: "@app1/composables/useAppConfig.js": "#imports", but it hasn't yielded the expected results.
